# How do I copy my dll and other binaries from bin folder in asp.net website to azure devops pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I just created an azure pipeline from bitbucket cloud and using the default generated yaml file, when i run the Run New pipeline, I am getting errors in VsBuild saying

```
    Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'RestSharp' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

The RestSharp.dll is located in my bin folder in asp.net website.

Looking at the raw logs, it says

```
    2020-07-10T03:35:57.7771564Z           Considered "d:\a\1\s\mywebsite\Bin\RestSharp.dll", but it didn't exist.
    2020-07-10T03:35:57.7772002Z           For SearchPath "{TargetFrameworkDirectory}".
    2020-07-10T03:35:57.7772374Z           Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\RestSharp.winmd", but it didn't exist.
    2020-07-10T03:35:57.7772874Z           Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\RestSharp.dll", but it didn't exist.
    ...
```

However, when I build in VS 2019, there are no build errors, since I am referencing my dlls and binaries.
How do I fix this missing dlls or referenced binaries? If I need to copy files from bin folder to the build directory, how?

Comment: Can you check if `d:\a\1\s\mywebsite\Bin\RestSharp.dll` is really committed to your repo?

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej I'm new to azure devops, but are you referring to my git repo? I do not push dlls to our repo.. is it ok to push these dll to repos? One thing, this is asp.net website that references a class library that references a RestSharp nuget package. Can that nuget package be copied to my asp.net website bin folder?

Comment: Your path `d:\a\1\s\mywebsite\Bin\RestSharp.dll` suggests that you do not reference nuget package but directly dll library. Can you add your csproj to question? At least part where you have your references.

Answer (score 0):

> Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'RestSharp' could not be found

Tested using .dll file path in bin folder as `HintPath`. I encountered the same issue.

It seems that the root cause of this issue is that the `RestSharp.dll` doesn't exist in the Bin folder at the time of reference.

This is my solution to solve this issue:

Step1: Add the package reference in `Packages.config` file.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
.....
  <package id="RestSharp" version="106.11.4" targetFramework="net472" />
</packages>
```

Step2: Change the  RestSharp `HintPath` in `.csproj` file. Since you add the package reference, you could directly get the RestSharp.dll in the package path.

For example:

```
<Reference Include="RestSharp">
  <Private>True</Private>
  <HintPath>..\packages\RestSharp.106.11.4\lib\net452\RestSharp.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Then the RestSharp.dll could be used in the build.

By the way, I recommend that you could turn them into packages, and restore them during build. Then you could get the dll files in the package path. This can avoid the error above.